# JavaFX TableView controls are not repainted correctly after remove item / add new item

Tags: javafx, controls, tableview

I am using an `ObservableList` to control the items and every time I **delete an item**, the `TableView` removes it from the datasource. But **the view is not being updated** as I'm still seeing all the items. The only difference is that the removed item can not be selected anymore.

Similar problem: [javafx listview and treeview controls are not repainted correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821319/javafx-listview-and-treeview-controls-are-not-repainted-correctly)

In the following the code:

```
final TableColumn<TMachineType, String> testerType = new TableColumn<TMachineType, String>(
            bundle.getString("table.testerType"));

    testerType
            .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TMachineType, String>(
                    "testerType"));

    testerType
            .setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<TMachineType, String>, TableCell<TMachineType, String>>() {

                @Override
                public TableCell<TMachineType, String> call(
                        final TableColumn<TMachineType, String> param) {
                    final TableCell<TMachineType, String> cell = new TableCell<TMachineType, String>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void updateItem(final String item,
                                final boolean empty) {
                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                            textProperty().unbind();
                            if (empty || item == null) {
                                setGraphic(null);
                                setText(null);
                            }
                            if (!empty) {
                                    final TMachineType row = (TMachineType) getTableRow().getItem();
                                    textProperty().bind(
                                            row.testerTypeProperty());
                                }

                        }
                    };
                    return cell;
                }
            });
```

TMachineType class:

```
private final SimpleStringProperty testerType = new SimpleStringProperty();

    @Column(name = "TESTER_TYPE")
public String getTesterType() {
    return testerType.get();
}

public void setTesterType(String testerType) {
    this.testerType.set(testerType);
}

public StringProperty testerTypeProperty() {
    return testerType;
}
```

Observable List:
 1. DB entities:

```
final Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM TMachineType t");
final List resultList = q.getResultList();
```

2. Obs. list setup:

```
    ObservableList<TMachineType> observableList;
...
    observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(resultList);
    tableMachineType.setItems(observableList);
    FXCollections.sort(observableList);
```

3. Row removal:

   ```
   @FXML
   private void handleOnRemove(final ActionEvent event) {

   final ObservableList<TMachineType> selectedIndices = tableMachineType
           .getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
   final String infoTxt = selectedIndices.size() + " "
           + bundle.getString("message.records_removed");

   final List<TMachineType> deleteBuffer = new ArrayList<TMachineType>();
   deleteBuffer.addAll(selectedIndices);

   for (final TMachineType selectedIdx : deleteBuffer) {

       selectedIdx.manufacturerProperty().unbind();
       selectedIdx.testerTypeProperty().unbind();

       deleted.add(selectedIdx);
       observableList.remove(selectedIdx);
       // tableMachineType.getItems().remove(selectedIdx);

   }
   ..
   ```

   }

Comment: Have you tested the solution proposed in the question you mention?

Comment: yes, see the edited code below..

Comment: `updateItem()` should be called first

Comment: Your `if (! isEmpty())` is inside your `if (empty || item == null)`. Is that the same in your actual code?

Comment: do you mean before textProperty().unbind(); ?

Comment: Yes. And also check @James_D comment

Comment: ok i have check, but the problem is still there.. :(

Comment: I have a couple of guesses... Try replacing `if (! isEmpty() )` with `if (! empty)`, though I think your `super.updateItem(...)` should ensure those are the same. Second, it's never a good idea to rely on both the `updateItem(...)` and `getIndex(...)`: you have no idea which is updated first. See if you can avoid calling `getIndex()` - perhaps use `getTableRow().getItem()` to get the "row item".

Comment: Can you show a little more of how this is set up: just some of your `TMachineType` class (the relevant bits for this column) and the `cellValueFactory` you use? It seems like this cell factory is more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: Thanks.
Tried to replace getIndex(..) with getTableRow().getItem(). Still doesn't work.
Funny thing: it works perfectly fine in Java7. Somehow Java8_25 is not handing it properly. Any ideas?

Comment: @James_D look at the updated code

Comment: What happens if you remove the `cellFactory` entirely? It seems like it isn't doing anything that doesn't happen by default.

Comment: @James_D
I need it to perform the binding:
textProperty().bind(row.testerTypeProperty());

Here's how it goes: above the table of rows there's a tiny form to edit the currently selected row. Once a row is selected, its values are displayed in the form (binding is created). When you edit the form, the binding form->row is being applied. Since the table cell text property is also binded with the row, changes applied to the row (in the form) are immediately applied to the text value of the selected cell.

Hence, I cannot remove the cellFactory.

Comment: That is default behavior.

Comment: yes you are right ! The cellFactory was actually redundant :)

I removed it. Unfortunately the original error is still there. Perhaps the fact that it works fine in Java7 is a clue?

Comment: Hard to tell. If it's not the cell factory that is causing the issue, it's probably something to do with your observable list. Show the code where you create the list and the code where you remove items from it. I suspect you are wrapping a regular list and manipulating the regular list instead of the observable list.

Comment: @James_D I've updated the code part. I posted the creation and removal of the rows in the list.

Comment: @James_D i have fixed the problem. it was really the cell factory that is causing the issue !! Thank you, good job !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing the cellFactory fix this problem ! YEHU :)

```
testerType
        .setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<TMachineType, String>, TableCell<TMachineType, String>>() {

            @Override
            public TableCell<TMachineType, String> call(
                    final TableColumn<TMachineType, String> param) {
                final TableCell<TMachineType, String> cell = new TableCell<TMachineType, String>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(final String item,
                            final boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        textProperty().unbind();
                        if (empty || item == null) {
                            setGraphic(null);
                            setText(null);
                        }
                        if (!empty) {
                                final TMachineType row = (TMachineType) getTableRow().getItem();
                                textProperty().bind(
                                        row.testerTypeProperty());
                            }

                    }
                };
                return cell;
            }
        });
```