# How can i use tree view in javafx 1.8

Tags: javafx-2

When i Run my Application on javafx 1.7 it works well. But when run it on javafx 1.8 it has a problem like this picture below. Please tell me how to fix it. Thank very much.

Here my source code:

```
    dataTreeView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(
            SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    dataTreeView.setShowRoot(false);
    dataTreeView
            .setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<Field>, TreeCell<Field>>() {
                @Override
                public TreeCell<Field> call(TreeView<Field> p) {
                    final TreeCell<Field> treeCell = new TreeCell<Field>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void updateItem(Field item, boolean empty) {
                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                            if (item != null) {
                                setText(item.toString());
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    return treeCell;
                }
            });
    paneDataTreeView.getChildren().add(dataTreeView);
    final TreeItem<Field> itemTree = new TreeItem<Field>(new Field(
            "Talent traffic company"));
    final TreeItem<Field> itemTree1 = new TreeItem<Field>(
            new Field("Yahoo"));
    final TreeItem<Field> itemTree2 = new TreeItem<Field>(new Field(
            "Microsoft"));
    itemTree.getChildren().add(itemTree1);
    itemTree.getChildren().add(itemTree2);
    dataTreeView.getRoot().getChildren().add(itemTree);
```

[image: Javafx 1.8 Error When I collapse tree View]

Comment: possible duplicate of [javafx listview and treeview controls are not repainted correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821319/javafx-listview-and-treeview-controls-are-not-repainted-correctly)

Comment: Thank you very much. that is my expecting