# Strange behaviour of observable lists

Tags: listview, javafx, event-handling, event-dispatch-thread, observablelist

I bound an observablelist with a Listview to perform my tasks on listview. type of listview and observablelist is a model that i defined in model layer.So i use cell factory to render a graphical node from my model objects. I should add an item to observablelist as user enter a text in a textField. My problem is when user enter a new text and i add items to observablelist some additional unexpectec items apear at listview. but if i add some items to observable list manualy out of event handler, list view works correctly. I think its because of some threading issues but i cant solve it.

here is a simple example that produce my problem:

FXMLDocumentController.java:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
@FXML
ListView<String> list;
ObservableList<String> ol;

@FXML
TextField text;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    ol = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    list.setItems(ol);
    list.setCellFactory((ListView<String> param) -> {
        ListCell<String> lc = new ListCell<String>(){
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty){
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if(!empty){
                    System.out.println("HI");
                    Parent root = null;
                    try {
                        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Entry.fxml"));
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                    }
                    ((Label)(root.lookup("#label"))).setText(item);
                    setGraphic(root);
                }
            }
        };
        return lc;
    });
    text.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        ol.add(text.getText());
        text.clear();
    });
}    
}
```

FXMLDoument.fxml:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="511.0" prefWidth="420.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="testapp.FXMLDocumentController">
<children>
  <ListView fx:id="list" layoutX="68.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="391.0" prefWidth="284.0" />
  <TextField fx:id="text" layoutX="110.0" layoutY="419.0" />
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Entry.fxml:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="250.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<children>
<Label fx:id="label" layoutX="70.0" layoutY="18.0" prefHeight="15.0" prefWidth="178.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="49.0" />
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Thanks in advances

Comment: If you can show us the code you have written to send data from `textfield to ObservableList`, it
 would be helpful.

Comment: 'Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)'.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. What are `newGroupText`, `GroupEntry`, `groups` and others? Please create a MCVE as suggested above by James.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha As i am newbie in here i did not know the correct way of asking questions . I added a sample to my question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821319/javafx-listview-and-treeview-controls-are-not-repainted-correctly