# Javafx TreeItem/TreeView UI crashes when collapsing the expanded node. Any help would be appreciated

Tags: java, javafx

Step to produce the bug

1. Run this code
2. Expand the root node, if not expanded
3. Collapse the root node
4. More folders (like subfolders) will appear at the end of the window

---

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class Main extends Application {

    Pane box;
    TreeView<String> treeView;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("Root");
        traverse("a folder path", root);
        root.setExpanded(true);

        treeView = new TreeView<String>(root);
        treeView.setShowRoot(true);
        treeView.setEditable(true);
        treeView.setPrefSize(500, 800);

        treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<String>, TreeCell<String>>() {
            @Override
            public TreeCell<String> call(TreeView<String> paramP) {
                return new TreeCell<String>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(String paramT, boolean paramBoolean) {
                        super.updateItem(paramT, paramBoolean);
                        if (!isEmpty()) {
                            setGraphic(new Label(paramT, (Node) importImage("image path")));
                            setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                                @Override
                                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                                    P.print(paramT);
                                    P.print(treeView.getChildrenUnmodifiable().size());
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        box = new Pane();
        box.getChildren().add(treeView);
        box.setPrefSize(500, 800);

        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 500, 800);

        stage.setTitle("Tree View Sample");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void traverse(String path, TreeItem<String> root) {
        File file = new File(path);

        if (!file.isDirectory() || !Files.isReadable(Paths.get(path)))
            return;
        Arrays.asList(file.listFiles()).forEach(e -> {
            TreeItem<String> temp = new TreeItem<>(e.getName());
            root.getChildren().add(temp);
            traverse(e.getPath(), temp);
        });

    }

    public static ImageView importImage(String path) {
        ImageView image = new ImageView(new Image(path));
        image.setPreserveRatio(true);
        image.setFitHeight(20);

        return image;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is crashes?  Is there a stack trace?  If so, can you add it as text to the question formatted as code?

Comment: Note that "crash" has a pretty standard meaning in software development. Typically, it means there was a critical and catastrophic failure that caused the entire process to terminate. Your description does not match that kind of failure. It seems you're simply seeing visual "artifacts", and based on the code provided, that's caused by the improper implementation of `updateItem` in your custom cell (see link by James_D).

Comment: Your example works if I follow the [API](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#updateItem(T,boolean)), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26822360/230513). If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: @jewelsea, thanks for the reply, there was not stack trace.

Comment: Thanks @Slaw and trashgod, I think the is duplicated question. The answer you guys pointed out fixed the issue I had.

Comment: Also consider `TreeView<File>` and `TreeItem<File>`.